# Module 'sportsStore' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 files:

App.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="SportsStore">
<head>
    <title>SportsStore</title>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="controllers/sportsStore.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("sportsStore", []);
    </script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="sportsStoreCtrl">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORTS STORE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            Categories go here
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="well" ng-repeat="item in data.products">
                <h3>
                    <strong>{{item.name}}</strong>
                    <span class="pull-right label label-primary">
                        {{item.price | currency}}
                    </span>
                </h3>
                <span class="lead">{{item.description}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

SportsStore.js

```
angular.module("sportsStore")
.controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        products: [
        {
            name: "Product #1", description: "A product",
            category: "Category #1", price: 100
        },
        {
            name: "Product #2", description: "A product",
            category: "Category #1", price: 110
        },
        {
            name: "Product #3", description: "A product",
            category: "Category #2", price: 210
        },
        {
            name: "Product #4", description: "A product",
            category: "Category #3", price: 202
        }]
    };
});
```

Why am I getting the following error in Chrome?

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'sportsStore' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling your module before initialize it

```
<script src="controllers/sportsStore.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module("sportsStore", []);

</script>
```

To create module

```
angular.module("sportsStore", []);
```

and to get module

```
angular.module("sportsStore");
```

Try like this

```
<script>
    angular.module("sportsStore", []);

</script>
<script src="controllers/sportsStore.js"></script>
```

or create module in your js

Like this

```
angular.module("sportsStore",[])
.controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope) {
```

Module name is case-sensitive.You are using module name

```
<html ng-app="SportsStore">
```

But in your js your module name is `sportsStore` .

Try like this

```
<html ng-app="sportsStore">
```

Answer (score 1):

In your html your module name is - SportsStore

```
i.e ng-app="SportsStore"
```

The module name in the app.js must be exactly similar to the value we defined in ng-app, which is true for **case sensitivity.**

```
angular.module("sportsStore") -- Wrong
```

It should be like

```
angular.module("SportsStore",[]) -- Right
```

You have to pass an **empty array for module** to work.

Below link is an example how to create module and start your application

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02